# Need some help trying to understand this code of matching for a graph

Tags: java, graph-algorithm

The code can be found here: https://sites.google.com/site/indy256/algo/kuhn_matching2

More specifically, I'm not sure I understand what the int n2 is for and how it is being used.

Comment: Why did you assume "The vertexes that are in set n2 are greater than or equal to (n1 + 1) but less than or equal to (n1 + n2)."? If I understand you correctly, your input should be `"3 3 3   0 0   1 1   2 0"`, at least this is what the author of the program assumed.

Comment: I don't think it will solve your problem, see my answer below. The algorithm works with 0-indexed arrays, increasing the size of matching will skew the algorithm. It is much easier to convert input the way I showed and then convert the output if you need to. As for printing, you only need to understand what matching contains at the end of the `maxMatching` method.

Comment: `matching` contains, for each edge originating in `n2` that counts towards max match, index of vertex in `n1` or -1 if this vertex does not count. Remember, that all indexes are 0-bound. In original example given by you (before you changed main) matching contains [0,-1,1], i.e. "coding can be done by John, nothing for QA, and support by Bob". I.e. it is inversed. You could also print it like this:
``System.out.println(Arrays.toString(matching));`` - then you need no loop. Have fun. What you are doing will require pretty good understanding of arrays, indexes and a little bit of graphs and sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, for [bipartite graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph), `n1` denotes number of vertices of the first set (partition) and `n2` denotes number of vertices of the second set.
E.g. you would have a set of workers and a set of tasks they would perform. In the example above, there are 2 workers (say `John=0` and `Bob=1`) and three tasks (say, `coding=0`, `QA=1`, `support=2`). 
John can do coding and support. Bob can do only support. None of them can do QA (there is no g[i] == 1)

Then the algorithm follows Kuhn's proposal to find a [maximum matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_matching) (do not confuse with maximal matching). In our example case, maximum matching has two edges (e.g. `John->coding` and `Bob->support`).

The algorithm above would not work for weighted bipartite graphs.

**Update**

To accommodate the input rules from the question, following needs to be done. Simpy ensure that in `g[x]=y` : `0 <= x < n1` and `0 <= y < n2`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  int n1 = sc.nextInt();
  int n2 = sc.nextInt();
  int m = sc.nextInt();
  LinkedList<Integer>[] g = new LinkedList[n1];
  for (int j = 0; j < n1; j++) {
    g[j] = new LinkedList<Integer>();
  }
  int i = 0;
  while(i != m){
    int v = sc.nextInt();
    int v2 = sc.nextInt();
    if(v>=1 && v<=n1) { 
        //v belongs in first set 
        g[v-1].add(v2-n1-1);
    }else if(v>=n1+1 && v<=n1+n2) { 
        //v belongs in the second set, v2 into the first
        g[v2-1].add(v-n1-1);
    }
    i++;
  }
  System.out.println(maxMatching(g, n2));
}
```

Comment: Okay. I'm just messing with this code a bit and I want to modify the input of the edges. I changed the main method to what I posted in the main post and I'm getting some errors.

Comment: Vertices are 0-indexed. The maxiumum index for n1==n2==3 is 2. If I answered your question, please, mark it.